# React not rendering - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, render, react-props

I'm having trouble with the first render of my application. I know the issue is because initially my 'const name' is undefined. When I set it to something such as a string, the app will load, and then I can put the original code back in and the app will work like it's supposed to. But if I refresh, I get the error again.
Here is my code:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    const name  = props.name.newMovement.movementName;
    const displayMovementButtons = () => {
        if (!name) {    
            return (
                <div className={classes.noMovementsMessage} >Click add button to begin</div> 
            )
        }

        return (
            <Button 
                className={classes.movementButtons}
                onClick={() => history.push('/movement/:id')}
            >   
                <div className={classes.movementName} >{name}</div>
            </Button>
        )
    };
```

So, 'name' is what starts off as undefined. How can I restructure my code so that it will do the initial render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `props.name` or `props.name.newMovement` is undefined. If you're working with async data it's likely that the `name` property hasn't been set at the time of the initial render. You can try [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so that your component doesn't immediately throw an error when the name property isn't defined.

```
const name  = props.name?.newMovement?.movementName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `{name ? name : ""}`
This checks if name is null. If so, it prints `""` , otherwise it prints whatever name is